# JS Function not running after button click: Uncaught TypeError: "functionName" is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have tried all different file paths to try and access the helperFunctions.js file, but nothing seems to work. Every time i click the register user button, it says that the function that I call does not exist/is not a function. This means the helperFunctions.js file is not being accessed.

Html part that adds file path and calls the function from helperFunctions.js.

```
<body>
    //other important core js files
    <script src="./js/helperFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

    <script>
    
            $(document).ready(function(){   
                        $('#registerUser').click(function() {
                            // call API to register user
                            registerUser();
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

HelperFunctions.js file and function

```
function registerUser() 
{

    console.log('step 1');
    //document.getElementById('label-error').style.display="none";
    //document.getElementById('label-mismatch').style.display="none";
    //document.getElementById('label-passwordsyntax').style.display="none";
    
    var userID = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var re_password = document.getElementById('repassword').value;
    var fname = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    
        console.log('step 1.1');
    
    if ((userID=='') || (pwd=='') || (re_password=='') || (fname=='') || (lname=='')) || (re_password==''))
        return false;

    var passw=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,14}$/;
    
    
    if (pwd.match(passw) == null)
    {
        //document.getElementById('label-passwordsyntax').style.display="inline";
        return false;
    }       
    
    console.log('step 2');
    
    if (pwd != re_password)
    {
        alert(pwd + "|" + re_password);
        document.getElementById('label-mismatch').style.display="inline";
        return false;
    }
    */
    
    var postObj = {
        email: userID,
        Pwd: pwd,
        rePwd: re_password,
        firstName: fname,
        lastName: lname
    };

console.log('step 3');

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', 'https://localhost:44303/api/JSON/registerUser', true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
    req.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {

            if (req.response=="-1")
                alert('user already exists');
                //document.getElementById('label-error').style.display="inline";
            
            if (req.response=="1") 
                alert('user created successfully');
                //location.href='login.html?action=success';        
        }
    }
    
    console.log('step 4');
    
    req.send(JSON.stringify(postObj));
    console.log('step 5');
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: how much steps get completed, and also *where is this function called `functionName`?*

Comment: No steps are completed because it doesn't even recognize the function, that's why I think its not even reaching the helperFunction.js file. Also functionName = registerUser().

Comment: that's EXACTLY why it wont work.. if i have `function a(){return 1}` and then i say `let x=a()`, `a==1` and `a is not a function`

Comment: what do *YOU* want `functionName` to be though

Comment: Well, firstly in the snippet I see misused `*/` right before `postObj`, it should be removed. Secondly `(lname==''))` has two closing parenthesis `)` one of them should be removed. Might be errors of this kind?

Comment: that is proof that the code never even reaches the part he sent us `HelperFunctions.js`

Comment: Also, try to come up with reproducible example, but using as small amount of code as possible. You can try to commenting and simplifiying some of the code parts until the problem disappears

Comment: Oh, yeah, most certainly the file didn't connect, but you call the function that is defined in the file, so the error is saying that there's no such function. Try checking path to the file and see console if it has any errors for not found files.

Comment: @TheBombSquad - Sorry for the confusion, I used the term "functionName" in case others have the same error where whatever function they might have isn't called. functionName is registerUser(). The error message I got in html developer tool console was "Uncaught TypeError: registerUser is not a function".

Comment: **FIX** the errors that @AlexChebotarsky mentioned **for sure** and if *that* doesn't work.. then in the `helperFunctions.js` file.. change the first line *from* `function registerUser()` *to* `window.registerUser=function()`

Comment: @AlexChebotarsky Thanks for pointing out those small errors, I fixed them, refreshed and tried again but still got the same error. I also tried multiple file paths, including the full path of C:\Capstone\Draft 3\pages\js\helperFunctions.js. I still have no idea what I'm missing or what the error is

Comment: Just wanted to say thankyou for all your help. I just decided to delete and make a new file with a new path location, and now I'm able to access the file and run the function. I don't really know what I messed up but I appreciate the time taken to help me out :) have a good day.